# How to compare the two variables

Tags: jmeter, correlation, string-comparison

How can we compare a variable having many values with a value which is we are going to parametrize

Consider the variable name `City`.

While correlation we are capturing all the cities in a page using -1

It captures all the names of cities like

```
City_1:*
City_2:*
City_3:*
City_N:*
```

No of cities may change every time.

New city:*****

How can we write code as that the new city is not present in city variables

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether your `New city` is present in the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you could use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) for this:

```
${__groovy(vars.entrySet().findAll{entry -> entry.getKey().matches('City_\\d+')}.collect {entry -> entry.getValue()}.contains('*****'),)}
```

Replace `*****` with your actual New city name, the function will return `true` if the new city is there and `false` otherwise.

In the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the __groovy() function.